# Как узнать версию Word?

Tags: windows, ms-word, c++

Подскажите, пожалуйста, алгоритм: как можно узнать с помощью С++ текущую версию MS Word на компьютере? Если их несколько, то ту, которая привязана к `.doc`. Достаточно будет алгоритма или названий функций, которые помогут решить задачу достаточно маленьким количеством кода.

Comment: Предложу вариант покопаться в OLE запросах к ворду, на msdn почитайте.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы тупо проверил реестр Windows, а именно значение ключа (и его подключей)

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office
```

Например если есть ключ: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\12.0` - значит стоит 2003 офис, ну и т.д.

Туча примеров про то как узнать значения ключа в реестре Windows [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34065/how-to-read-a-value-from-the-windows-registry)

**Update**

Есть еще вариант вызвать через OLE automation функцию VB `Application.version`, IMHO первый вариант все равно дешевле

Answer (score 3):

В реестре по адресу `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.doc` достаешь значение переменной `(Default)`, которая в корне и там находится значение такого типа "`Word.Document.8`", что значит "`Word 97 8.0`" . Достаешь это значение и дальше определяешь какая это версия. Вот таблица версий

```
Year Released   Name    Version Comments
1989    Word for Windows 1.0
1990    Word for Windows 1.1    1.1 Code-named Bill the Cat
1990    Word for Windows 1.1a   1.1a    For Windows 3.1
1991    Word for Windows 2.0    2.0 Code-named Spaceman Spiff
1993    Word for Windows 6.0    6.0 Code-named T3 (renumbered 6 to bring Windows version numbering in line with that of DOS version, Macintosh version and also WordPerfect, the main competing word processor at the time; also a 32-bit version for Windows NT only)
1995    Word 95 7.0 Included in Office 95
1997    Word 97 8.0 Included in Office 97
1998    Word 98 8.5 Only sold as part of Office 97 Powered By Word 98, which was only available in Japan and Korea.
1999    Word 2000   9.0 Included in Office 2000
2001    Word 2002   10.0    Included in Office XP
2003    Office Word 2003    11.0    Included in Office 2003
2006    Office Word 2007    12.0    Included in Office 2007; released to businesses on November 30, 2006, released worldwide to consumers on January 30, 2007
2010    Word 2010   14.0    Included in Office 2010
```

Вот [статья](http://www.simple-smart.ru/detect-office-version/) на C#, я думаю, перевести на С++ особого труда вам не составит.

Comment: Спасибо. Но странно, что у меня пишет "Word.Document.8" Хотя запускается 2003 11-ый.

Comment: Хм, значит оно пишет именно версию Word`а, в которой оно было включено (Included in Office 97), а не к которой версии Word`а оно привязано.